# Jquery Live Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant get the jquery live click to work, it works fine in IE8 but the live click event never fires in Mozilla.

```js
   $("li.lidropdown").live("click", function(e) {

    alert("click");
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("a.linkplaylistbutton").text(text);


    if (text == 'Large Icons') {

        //RenderLargeIconsPlaylist();

    }
    else {

        //RenderDetailsPlaylist();

    }
    $("ul.uldropdownplaylistaddmedia").hide();
  });
```

```html
<div id="ctl150" class="divplaylistcontainer">
   <a class="linkplaylistbutton" onclick="javascript:PlaylistViewClick(this)">Details</a>
   <a class="linkselectedbuttondropdown" onclick="javascript:PlaylistViewClick(this)"></a>
   <ul class="uldropdownplaylistaddmedia" style="display: block;">
        <li class="lidropdown">Large Icons</li>
        <li class="lidropdown">Details</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If it doesn't work in Mozilla, it means that $('li.lidropdown') is not returning any elements in Mozilla.  So check that.  The live function works just fine in all browsers, as far as I've ever seen.

Comment: see if this class exist, put just a alert inside the click, try debugind with firebug .................

Comment: Can you give the HTML code so that it will be easy to figure out the error.

Comment: Another possibility is that something else cancels the live function (die or unbind) in Mozilla only, or possibly the removeEventListener method is being called.  In short, I doubt that the problem is with live.

Comment: where the `text` variable are coming from ?

Comment: @ric_bfa , ive modified the code i missed out that line. In jsfiddle when i paste the snippet of code in my full js file it works but when i paste the full js file the jsfiddle doesnt work and the click never happens  http://jsfiddle.net/BDPPN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your code into jsfiddle and tried it in Firefox, and I see the alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/BDPPN/

Comment: yeah your correct that ists working in jsfiddle, but its also working in IE8, safari and even opera but not mozilla

Answer (score 1):

It should work, you might have a problem with the generated content, do an HTML validation on it. [Firefinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/) could also help.

Also, this looks suspicios:

```
$("a.linkplaylistbutton").text(text);
```

did you mean:

```
text = $("a.linkplaylistbutton").text();
```